# Opening a word document in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to open  word document in ASP.net. The document exists inside the ASP.net application under the folder c:\AppName\Word Docs\Requirements Docs.docx
 This is the way I am trying to open it:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkReqDoc" runat="server"  Text="App Requirements"  ></asp:LinkButton>
```

and the code behind is like this:

```
Protected Sub lnkReqDoc_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkReqDoc.Click

        Dim fs1 As FileStream = New FileStream("~/word Docs/", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim data1() As Byte = New Byte(fs1.Length) {}
        fs1.Read(data1, 0, data1.Length)
        fs1.Dispose()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "Requirements Docs.docx")
        Response.BinaryWrite(data1)
        Response.End()
        fs1.Close()
    End Sub
```

When I tried to open the document on my local, I am getting an error saying:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\~\word Docs\'.
```

On my local, if I just do the below line then it works fine, it opens the word document, but when I deploy the below code on server then it says "File or directory not found"

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkReqDoc" runat="server"  Text="App Requirements" PostBackUrl="~/word Docs/Requirements.docx" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

what should I exactly do to open the file both on server and local.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The issue is coming from the path. By default it goes to Visual Studio folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0`). Take a look at this Path to get the file path in Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, thanks. Path was the issue.